# Merging a pull request to my fork

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have created a fork of [jimson gem](https://github.com/chriskite/jimson) repository.

How I can merge this [pull request](https://github.com/chriskite/jimson/pull/28) to my fork

Comment: Typically if GitHub can automatically do the merge there will be a green button indicating this.  That this button is not present likely either means that you do not have the rights to do this, or a build is happening which is preventing GitHub from giving you the go ahead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you think is there a way to get those changes and apply them into my fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) lets you give a URL for a repository, so you can use something like:

```
git pull https://github.com/mitfik/jimson.git next
```

Comment: can you explain please how I can pull that to my fork ?

Comment: First, you pull it to your local repository. Then, just push the updated branch back to github once everything looks good.

Comment: I removed the original fork and I forked https://github.com/mitfik/jimson instead, should that work ?